# Can argument be a more general class than parameter being passed?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, shuffle

The more specific question is, I want to be able to shuffle an array, whether it contains integers, strings, objects or something else. Using `Comparable` type seems to be problematic, and I don't want to use `int[]` or `String[]` because I want to use a more general class that allows arrays of all of these types to be shuffled using the same Shuffle class.

Here's my code.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Shuffle
{
    public Shuffle() {}

    public void shuffle(Comparable[] a)
    {
        int n= a.length;
        int j;
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            j= (int)(Math.random()*(i+1));
            if (i!=j) swap(a, i, j);
        }
    }

    protected void swap(Comparable[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        Comparable temp= a[i];
        a[i]= a[j];
        a[j]= temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that you can't, in Java, substitute an array of `int` for an array of some object class.  The "scalars" -- char, short, int, long, float, double, and bool -- cannot be dealt with generically.  Everything else can be in an array of `Object[]` if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `shuffle` and `swap` methods aren't using `compareTo`, so there is no reason to make the type `Comparable`.

In this case, an `Object[]` seems to be the best option, as a replacement for `Comparable[]`.  Any objects can be shuffled.  That's as general as it gets.